# Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (14724, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm, keras-layer

Trying to build a single output regression model, but there seems to be problem in the last layer

```
inputs = Input(shape=(48, 1))
lstm = CuDNNLSTM(256,return_sequences=True)(inputs)
lstm = Dropout(dropouts[0])(lstm)

#aux_input
auxiliary_inputs = Input(shape=(48, 7))
auxiliary_outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(4))(auxiliary_inputs)
auxiliary_outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(7))(auxiliary_outputs)

#concatenate
output = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm, auxiliary_outputs])

output = TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='linear'))(output)
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='linear'))(output)
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(output)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs, auxiliary_inputs], outputs=[output])
```

I am new to keras... I am getting the following error

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (14724, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, think I found a fix
According to - https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/ it says that we are applying dense layer to each timestep (in my case I have 48 timesteps). So, the output of my final layer would be (batch_size, timesteps, dimensions) for below:

```
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(output)
```

will be (?,48,1) hence the dimensions mismatch. However, If I want to convert this to single regression output we will have to flatten the final TimeDistributed layer

so I added the following lines to fix it:

```
output = Flatten()(output)
output = (Dense(1, activation='linear'))(output)
```

so now the timedistributed layer flattens to 49 inputs(looks like a bias input is included) to the final dense layer into a single output.

Okay, the code works fine and I am getting proper results(the model learns). My only doubt is if it is mathematically okay to flatten TimeDistributed layer to simple dense layer to get my result like stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a more on the context of your problem? Test data or at least more code. Why are you choosing this architecture in the first place?  Would a simpler architecture (just the LSTM) do the trick?  What are you regressing?  Stacking multiple TimeDistributed Dense layers with linear activation functions probably isn't adding much to the model.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I could just use a LSTM but it dint give me satisfactory results. The input of lstm is 48 timestep sequence and I want to predict the next timestep (the 49th). Each time step comes with additional data (48, 7) (7 features)which is fed via the aux-input. I am trying to concat the output of lstm with the auxiliary-outputs.