# How to fix Activation layer dimensions for LSTM in keras with masked layer

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keras

After looking at the [following gist](https://gist.github.com/dirko/1d596ca757a541da96ac3caa6f291229), and doing some basic tests, I am trying to create a NER system using a LSTM in `keras`. I am using a generator and calling `fit_generator`.

Here is my basic `keras` model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=True),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True)),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size)),
    Activation('softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

My input dimension seem right:

```
>>> generator = generate()
>>> i,t = next(generator)
>>> print( "Inputs: {}".format(model.input_shape))
>>> print( "Outputs: {}".format(model.output_shape))
>>> print( "Actual input: {}".format(i.shape))
Inputs: (None, 3949)
Outputs: (None, 3949, 1)
Actual input: (45, 3949)
```

However when I call:

```
model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

I seem to get the following error:

```
ValueError: 
  Error when checking target: 
    expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, 
    but got array with shape (45, 3949)
```

I have seen a few other examples of [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782596/error-when-checking-target-expected-time-distributed-5-to-have-3-dimensions-bu), which leads me to believe I need to `Flatten()` my inputs before the `Activation()` but if I do so I get the following error.

```
Layer flatten_1 does not support masking, 
but was passed an input_mask: 
    Tensor("embedding_37/NotEqual:0", shape=(?, 3949), dtype=bool)
```

As per previous questions, my generator is functionally equivalent to:

```
def generate():
    maxlen=3949
    while True:
        inputs = np.random.randint(55604, size=maxlen)
        targets = np.random.randint(2, size=maxlen)
        yield inputs, targets
```

I am not assuming that I need to `Flatten` and I am open to additional suggestions.

Comment: Could you provide us a `generator` code?

Comment: I updated the question with a generator that is generating random arrays of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to return only the last element of the sequence (`return_sequences=False`):

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=True),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size)),
    Dense(out_size),
    Activation('softmax')
])
```

Or remove the masking (`mask_zero=False`) to be able to use `Flatten`:

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=maxlen),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True)),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size)),
    Flatten(),
    Activation('softmax')
])
```

*Be careful that the output will be `out_size x maxlen`.

And I think you want the first option.

**Edit 1:** Looking at the example diagram, it makes a prediction on every timestep, so it need the softmax activation also `TimeDistributed`. The target dimension should be `(None, maxlen, out_size)`:

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=True),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True)),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size)),
    TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax'))
])
```

Comment: If I try to do the first option, and remove the `return_sequences=True` and `TimeDistributed` then I will get `Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (45, 3949)
`

Comment: The error says that your output is `(None, 1)` but your target size is `(None, 3949)`, assuming `out_size = 1` and `maxlen = 3949`, I think you have the second option `out_size x maxlen`. Also are you sure that you want a softmax activation? Sorry I'm not familiarized with NER systems, however I can help you get your outputs right if you have a diagram of your network.

Comment: masked values are needed since the vectors passed in are `padded` as seen [in an example here](http://dirko.github.io/Bidirectional-LSTMs-with-Keras/).

Comment: Updated my answer, be sure to check the target shape (maxlen,out_size)